Swiper Js 11 version On change event is not working
In Swiper slider by using version 11. I am expecting output as progress bar and fraction show together in the slider, when slide changes fraction and progress bar should change.
I tried by changing on event "slideChange" to "swiperslidechange" but it is not working.
My code:
<body>
<div class="swiper">
    <div id="fraction" class="swiper-fraction"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=1" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=2" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=3" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=4" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=5" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=6" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
const fraction = document.getElementById("fraction");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
const slideCount = slides.length;
fraction.textContent = `1 / ${slideCount}`;
 
  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
      
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 10,

    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: "progressbar",
      },
   
    on: {
    swiperslidechange: () => {
      fraction.textContent = `${swiper.realIndex + 1} / ${slideCount}`;
    }
  }
 
  });


</script>


Instead of arrow function use normal function inside the swiper init as below and change the swiper.realIndex to this.realIndex.
on: {
slideChange: function () {
fraction.textContent = `${this.realIndex + 1} / ${slideCount}`;
}
}

Solution 02:
Add the "on" event outside the swiper initialize
swiper.on('slideChange', () => {
fraction.textContent = `${swiper.realIndex + 1} / ${slideCount}`;
})



const fraction = document.getElementById("fraction");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
const slideCount = slides.length;
fraction.textContent = `1 / ${slideCount}`;
 
  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    autoplay: {
      delay: 2000,
    },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 10,

    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: "progressbar",
     
    },
   on: {
      slideChange: function () {
      fraction.textContent = `${this.realIndex + 1} / ${slideCount}`;
    } }
  });
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


body {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Segoe UI",Roboto,sans-serif;
    
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.swiper-slide {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  color: #fff;
}

  .swiper .swiper-pagination * {
    background: crimson;
  }


.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: crimson;
}


.swiper-fraction {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper">
    <div id="fraction" class="swiper-fraction"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=1" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=2" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=3" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=4" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=5" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=6" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=7" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=8" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random=9" alt="">
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>



